# -webkit-scrollbar works differently when using mobile simulator of chrome (when scrollbar is on html element)

Tags: css, google-chrome

I tried to customize the styles of scrollbar on chrome with `-webkit-scrollbar`.

Here is my css snippet:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: red;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Basically it makes scrollbar to be 12px wide, set track to be red, and scrollbar handle to blue.

This works fine on chrome, but when I turn on the mobile simulator, the scrollbar will go back to browser default.

Is it an intended behavior of chrome, or I missed something here?

UPDATE

People mentioned this demo: https://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/ works on both mobile and desktop.

But the point it works is because the `position:absolute` style on body caused the scrollbar is attached on body element. I find if scrollbar is on body, it works for both mobile and desktop.

If we remove that style from body, the scrollbar will go to html element. And we will see it works different on mobile and desktop.

Comment: Pls provide example link

Comment: The demo under https://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/ shows the same custom scrollbar, no matter whether I emulate mobile or desktop.

Comment: @CBore, thank you for pointing out. However, that demo only works because its body has `position: absolute` style. If you remove it, you will see exactly my question here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `-webkit-appearance: none;` to your `::-webkit-scrollbar` for it to work

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
For example adding a code snippet which solves the issue might help.